# Change name of month in Material Ui React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, material-ui, date-fns

I use DatePicker from Material Ui. I need to change the name of the month. How can I do it?

For example, I have to change from August to Avqust or from March to Mart [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37kQq.png)

My code:

```
             <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                  label=""
                  value={selectedDate}
                  minDate={"02-01-1920"}
                  maxDate={"02-29-2020"}
                  onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setSelectedDate(newValue);
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Do you maybe need to localize it? https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#localization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `local` prop of `LocalizationProvider`, to change the language of `DatePicker`'s days and months.
change the locale for the `date-fns` adapter.

From Documentation of Mui: https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#localization

```
import { az } from "date-fns/locale";

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={az}>
   <DatePicker
      label=""
      value={selectedDate}
      minDate={new Date("02-01-1920")}
      maxDate={new Date("02-29-2020")}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
         setSelectedDate(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
   />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/localizeddatepicker-material-demo-forked-uppsz8?file=/demo.js

**Update June 2023**

Change local using `dayjs` in `MUI` new version:

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/az";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";

export default function LocalizationDayjs() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="az">
      <DatePicker label="Date" defaultValue={dayjs("2022-04-17")} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-nova-tp7zsf?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Yeah, It worked 'en 'and 'ru'. But another problem is that the main language of my project is 'az'. I think 'az' does not support date-fns. Because I could not find 'az' folder in there, there are 'en-us' and 'ru'. There are only 3 countries starting with A (2 Arabic and 1 African, not Azerbaijani). The version is @date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13".

Comment: "date-fns/locale" contains many languages, including 'az' : https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/tree/master/src/locale .
This's your example with 'az' language:
https://codesandbox.io/s/localizeddatepicker-material-demo-forked-uppsz8?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved. The main problem was that date-fns was an old version. That's why 'az' did not work. I compared my package.json and your package.json and the problem was solved.

Comment: It doesn't working in codesandbox

Comment: I updated the answer with 2 working codesandbox demo with 2 different versions of MUI.